# iPhone OS 3 SDK?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

How can I install the iPhone OS 3 SDK beside the iOS 4 SDK? Is it possible?

Comment: Question already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html