# how to install two versions of xcode

Tags: xcode

I have one version of xcode installed in my mac and now I want to install the new version but I want to keep the old one also. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I installed Xcode 4 it automatically went into it's own folder at the root level. To make sure when you are installing check the install location and make sure it is not `/Developer` if for some reason it is just change it.