# submit an ios app using ios5 OS and ios5 sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, beta, ios5

I'm wondering if I can install IOS 5 and the IOS 5 SDK and still be able to develop and submit apps to Apple? Or once I install IOS 5 I'm forced to install the IOS5 SDK (from what I understand I can't test my applications using a stable 4.3 SDK when running my iDevice with new IO 5)

So am I able to develop my applications using IOS5 + IOS5 SDK and can I submit my applications to apple or will I need to wait for an official release of the stable version of IOS5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install [several Xcode versions next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413301/how-to-install-two-versions-of-xcode) and thus use the non-beta for submitting to the AppStore. Actually I recommend to always install the Xcode betas somewhere else in case you run into issues. For example, the Xcode 4.0 betas sometimes had so many crashes that it was PIA to use them. Going back to an older version isn't an issue if you still have it around.

Also, Apple doesn't care (or know) which iOS you're using on your device, they only care against which SDK you've linked.

Answer (score 3):

No-one currently using iOS5 can talk about it without breaking the NDA that they agreed to prior to downloading the new SDK. I suggest you read the release notes and other associated documentation before proceeding.

Having said that, usually the best strategy with beta releases is to install the SDK along-side the current, production version. Obviously you can't do this with your iOS device, but you shouldn't be installing a beta on your primary device anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell - you can install iOS 5 with Xcode 4.2 and still submit applications to apple. However you will only be able to submit applications linked against version 4.3 of the SDK, NOT 5.

You will only be able to submit app's linked against version 5 once it is released stable.

Comment: But from what i remember every time I update my iPhone to a new OS version (ex: from 4.2 to 4.3) I had to update the SDK to the latest  SDK. My question is: can i update my iPhone to the IOS 5 and still be able to develop and submit apps to apple?

Comment: Ive just updated my ipad2 to ios 5. It won't let me test apps with the current version of XCode (4.0.2) and the version 4.3 of the SDK. You would have to download the pre-release version of Xcode and the new beta SDK (4.2 of xcode and 5.0 of the SDK) to test "on device". You will still be able to submit/develop against 4.3 for the appstore.