# Can iOS SDK 5.0 be safely installed next to 4.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I've been waiting with installing the iOS 5.0 SDK, because I worry I might not be able to switch to the 4.3 SDK again. Can anyone tell me if it's possible / safe to upgrade to the 5.0 SDK beta and still be able to use the 4.3 SDK for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [install 2 or more xcode versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413301/how-to-install-two-versions-of-xcode) on the same machine. I would suggest doing this so that you can still submit from a non-beta version to the app store if required.

I've done it lots of times without any problems.

Comment: Thanks, I'll install it in **/SDK 5.0** so I can use both SDKs :)

Comment: Unfortunately they have shared resources that clashed when I tried.  Took me a while to clean it up.  In the past I've always had a clean OS install on an external disk, and used all beta products there.  Keeps you mentally separated, and always my preference.  - - - i don't think this happens to everyone, don't know what caught me, just it was lots of hours to clean

Comment: you **cannot ever downgrade** a device, once you 5 Beta an iPhone/iPad there's no going back