# Preserving the previous SDK when installing a new iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

Each time I install a new version of the SDK I lose the previous one. I want to use the new SDK, but I need to build using the oldest one.
Is there any method to keep the installed SDk when installing a new one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple XCode versions installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

Answer (score 3):

The recommended approach is to set the base SDK to the latest one but change the deployment target to the version you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple versions simultaneously.
Just give a different path while installing.
But I had problems while having both versions together.
The main problem I noticed was in the code sense of the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, you’ll have to follow @Govind’s advice on installing each Xcode version to a separate path. Unofficially, you can extract the SDK from the installer using a tool like Pacifist and keep it around. This is, of course, unsupported and undocumented.