# How can I use xcode 4 with xcode 3? (Three20 framework related problem)

Tags: iphone, xcode, three20

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have multiple XCode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

Hello,

When I installed Xcode 4 GM version, I lost my previous xcode 3.

It looks like that I cannot use with Xcode 4 with Xcode 3.

Is there anyway to use them together?

In fact, I want to use Three20 framework in my project, but Three20 scripts have not supported Xcode 4 yet.

Comment: Xcode 4 is still under NDA and shouldn't be discussed in an open forum. However, Apple has provided a private forum where it can be discussed...I would suggest checking out https://devforums.apple.com/community/xcode4

Answer (score 0):

Choose a different install location.

Comment: umm... my question was closed, but just in case, I record my result.
Choosing a different install location is not working. I already tried this method. (Install Xcode 3 at /Developer_3 , and then install Xcode 4 at /Developer) When I run Xcode 4, Xcode 4 is crashed.