# Uninstall Xcode 4 and use Xcode 3

Tags: xcode

I am having problems with SVN and also provisioning with Xcode 4 and I want to uninstall it.

How do I uninstall Xcode 4 and will I be fine using Xcode 3 from now on or what does everyone recommend.

Comment: You shouldn't need to uninstall Xcode 4.  You should be able to use Xcode 3 alongside it: [Can I have multiple XCode versions installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed) .  Have you filed bug reports on the SVN and provisioning issues you've been having?  The only way they'll get fixed is if you do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uninstalling Xcode is [pretty straightforward](http://macdevelopertips.com/xcode/how-to-uninstall-xcode.html), and involves the use of the Terminal:

```
sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

where `<Xcode>` should be replaced by the path to which the tools were installed (e.g., `/Developer`).

Comment: The default mode is `all` so you only really need `--mode=...` for partial uninstalls.

Comment: Does this _only_ uninstall Xcode4? What about other non-xcode developer tools? Like git or homebrew?

Answer (score 7):

If you really do want to uninstall rather than just have two or more versions co-existing then use:

```
/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools
```