# how to uninstall xcode and install another version?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninstall Xcode 4 and use Xcode 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463436/uninstall-xcode-4-and-use-xcode-3)

I am Abbas. I am new to iPhone Programming.

Tomorrow I have updated my xcode to 4.2 from version 3.2, But i am having problem to use it.

I have to uninstall xcode 4.2 from my mac and install xcode 3.2.

I have setup of both the version, but i do not know the procedure to uninstall xcode.

So.

Please Help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal and use this command:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

if your XCode is in different directory, use that path. After that you can delete the rest of the /Developer directory.

Comment: i do not want to uninstall all devtools.I only want to uninstall xcode. Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

From Xcode 4.3, the xcode is available on mac app store. If you download it from mac app store, it will be installed in this folder: `/Applications/Xcode.app`.

If xcode version is below 4.3, the installation directory can be changed in the installation wizard. The default installation directory is in `/Developer` folder. And if you choose the default folder when install xcode4.2 and the xcode3.2 is also in that folder. The xcode3.2 will be over written and removed.

If you want to keep both xcode 4.2 and 3.2, you can install them in different folder. For example, I installed xcode 3.2 in folder `/xcode3` and xcode 4.2 in folder `/xcode4`, and I also have a xcode4.3 in folder  `/Applications/Xcode.app`.

The problem is the newest ios simulator is only available in the lastest xcode. For example, the ios5.1 simulator is only available in xcode4.3 . So, maybe we should spend time to get familiar with the lastest xcode.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes you are right. But when i open xcode from my Dock it is opening xcode 3.2 but when i want to edit my any xib(nib) files it is opening new interface builder.and in my new interface builder when i double click any view it is not opening. What i have to do is remove both the xcode and install only single xcode version 3.2 because i am student and xcode 4.2 and it's interface builder is very hard to use according to xcode 3.2.So, Please help me, I am waiting for your  suggestion and Thanks for giving me this useful information.

Comment: This is my way: I use spotlight and input `xcode`, there will be 2 xcode application exist in the spotlight, with the installation folder followed. Then I will choose the xcode4 and open it. If I click the xib file in xcode4, the integrated IB will show, and I think it should be editable.