# Is it possible to install Xcode 3 after we have installed Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, xcode3.2

I have Xcode 4 on my Mac. Is it possible to install Xcode 3 say in directory other than /Developer?

Please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple XCode versions installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer is yes, since they can be installed separate directories.

[Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

Answer (score 1):

You should re-install XCode4 after you install XCode 3, as it can install slightly older versions of some things XCode 4 relies on.