# Switch between Xcode 4.0.2 and 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am developing an app with Xcode 4.0.2 and iOS 4.3. Now I would like to upgrade to Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 so that I could make my app ready when iOS 5 releases in October.

I am told by Apple's website that I should not submit apps that are built by Xcode 4.2 and should do it with the older Xcode 4.0.2, since the Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 thing is still in beta.

But in the following few weeks I still need to have newer versions of my app submitted to App Store. So my question is,

1. If I upgrade my Xcode to 4.2, is it possible for me to switch back to Xcode 4.0.2?
2. If yes, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply install two versions of Xcode at the same time. During the installation it will let you choose the destination folder; you can pick another folder. For example, I use `/Developer/Xcode (4.2)`. (However, if you did install 4.2 over 4.0.2, I don't think you would have a problem if you just ran the 4.0.2 installer again to downgrade.)

Comment: I had to completely uninstall all developer tools using "sudo <Xcode>/Library uninstall-devtools --mode=all" when going 4.2 -> 4.0.2 to get archives to sign correctly.

Comment: Its my first time with ios and I want to upgrade from 4.0.2 to 4.2 too. Can I keep using snow leopard or do I have to use Lion?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from `About Xcode.pdf` (`<Xcode>/About\ Xcode.pdf`)

> **Installation**
>   The Xcode installer will create the folder /Developer on the root of your boot partition, and place the Xcode developer tools and SDKs in this folder. If you have a previous version of Xcode you would like to preserve, you can copy the existing installation from /Developer to another folder to prevent having it updated automatically by the installer.

I would be cautious of this note (possible problems from incompatibility of tools???)

> **NOTE**: The Xcode installer also installs system components and UNIX command line tools in a shared location on your Mac. Only one version of these components can exist on a computer at a time, and the last installed version replaces any previously installed set.

I always make sure I have a bootable drive with a decent working copy of xcode ready for releases in case I need to push a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can install 2 XCode in different folders.
Then you can switch back and forth.

[Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)