# How to debug application on newer iOS version from an older version of xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to debug my application running on a newer ios version but use my older version of xcode. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You must have the iOS sdk then only you can debug, I think

Comment: Three downvotes. Probably because my question included the number 7.

Comment: I am literally running my app on ios 7 right now, launched and managed by 4.6. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you'll need to have multiple versions of xcode installed.

[Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

Xcode shares device and symbol information across all versions of xcode. If you open the newer xcode version that supports the newer version of ios, you can add the device there. Once the device is added, close the newer version of xcode, and open your older version (4.6) that you want to deveop on. If everything went smoothly the device should be available in organizer, and you should be able to run and debug normally on it.