# Install multiple versions of Apple LLVM on MacOS Maverick (10.9)

Tags: xcode, macos

To test the portability of a piece of code, I would like to install both Apple/LLVM 4.2 (based on LLVM 3.2svn, from XCode 4), and Apple/LLVM 5.0 (based on LLVM 3.3svn, from XCode 5) on the same machine, running Maverick (10.9). I do not need XCode itself, only the compiler suite. Is there a recommended way to install two different versions of Apple/LLVM?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed?rq=1. The easiest way may be to install multiple versions of Xcode and use the `xcode-select` tool to switch between them.