# Can I run Xcode 6.3.2 side by side with Xcode 6.2?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to run Xcode 6.3.2 side by side with Xcode 6.2, but I can't get my project to build.

I downloaded 6.3.2 from Apple Developer portal, and copied to my Applications folder as "Xcode632".

I can open it and compile my project, to a point. Initially it found all kinds of errors in my project related to Swift 1.2. I fixed those manually and now it compiles with no errors, but it never finishes building. It hangs at the point where it says "Compiling Swift source files".

I've tried changing my command line tools to 6.3.2 under Preferences | Locations. I've also cleaned my project, deleted derived data, restarted Xcode, restarted my computer. Nothing helps.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The answers provided in the other question are more than 5 years old and don't apply, and the accepted answer links to an article on Apple's site that is no longer there.

Comment: Why you want to do this? Usually people run Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 side-by-side or even Xcode 4 to support old projects, but to versions of Xcode 6, what's the point?

Comment: Xcode 6.3.2 includes Swift 1.2 which requires converting code. May not be a big deal, but I want to make sure I am not going to run into any serious problems before converting my project. I want to have the option to fall back and run 6.2 a little longer if necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

Comment: Thanks, but nothing there answers my question. Most of the answers on that post are more than 5 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I follow these steps:

1. compress my existing Xcode directory ( /Applications/Xcode.app ) to an archive ( Xcode.app.zip )
2. Update Xcode (for example 6.1 -> 6.2)
3. extract the archive somewhere else ( -> ~/Desktop/Xcode.app )
4. rename the old app ( -> ~/Desktop/Xcode61.app
5. move old Xcode app to /Applications ( -> /Applications/Xcode61.app )

I usually have problems when trying to install things into a differently named directory and keeping the old one where it was. For me the only reliable way was to archive the existing app and extract it to a different name.

Comment: @0yeoj Simply renaming sometimes resulted in the update to remove all previous versions :-)

Comment: And don't forget to re-run `xcode-select` if you want to use the command line tools.

Comment: You should re-run xcode-select -switch <path> in any event.  Xcode basically sits on the unix command line when it runs.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me to run Xcode 6.3.2 side by side with 6.2. Unfortunately, I'm still having a problem converting my project to Swift 1.2, but I am certain it is a project-specific problem and not related to running Xcode side by side.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Glad it helped. So far I never had problems when running Xcode versions side by side. (At least I don't remember any.) With Swift I have to play around a lot to make things work, as things seems to be slightly different than one can read in several places. I would assume the build issue is a project issue (or an "incomplete settings migration" problem :-) )