# Can XCode 7 and 7.1 beta coexist in the same Mac?

Tags: installation, swift2, xcode7.1beta

I'm using XCode 7 right now, but since I've got the Apple TV Dev Kit I'm just wondering if I can install and use XCode 7.1 too without removing 7.
Thanks!

Comment: You can find youranswer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  You'll have an application called Xcode.app and another called Xcode-beta.app.

The only issue is if you use the command line tools.  You'll need to use [xcode-select](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html) to switch between them.