# Xcode 9 alongside Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

**Installation of Xcode 9 is now totally and completely different from previous versions.**

**The previous 100s of explanations on the net and on SO of how to do this pre-8 are no longer useful**

After this dialog,

[image]

[image]

Xcode9 wants to make changes.

In fact, will it erase my 8.3.3 ?

Do you have to "move 8.3.3 to another folder, before clicking that button?"

What really is the best pipeline to have both 8.3.3 and 9 ?

---

Considering the magnificent answer of emlai below,

a further subtlety is that Xcode9 then wants to ...

[image]

will it hork the Xcode8 components and tools????

---

Interestingly, I found that running Xcode9 once happened to *eliminate all the simulators* for my Xcode 8 installation!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

Comment: hi @Suhaib, please please please do not mark as a duplicate.  **The system is now totally different with Xcode 9**.  Can you please remove the duplicate, because bypassers just click "duplicate" when they see a "duplicate" flag.

Comment: I don't know how to remove it. But no need to worry, I have submitted around 100 dups flags for iOS questions and not a single one of them got closed. Anyway it says: `possible dup`. So it can be considered more like a reference than a flag :-)

Comment: @Rob - fair enough man. But I just found for example it erased all my simulators from 8.  Not a big deal but someone with mini-bandwidth will be crying about this.

Comment: There is one problem. The Xcode 8 and Xcode 9 share the same preference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In fact, will it erase my 8.3.3 ?

No.

> Do you have to "move 8.3.3 to another folder, before clicking that button?"

No.

Beta Xcodes are named `Xcode-beta.app` so you can keep them in the same applications folder as the non-beta version.

Comment: It would be quite funny if you were lying, as a prank   :)

Answer (score 3):

From the *first page* of the Xcode 9 release notes:

> Xcode 9 ... can coexist with previous versions of Xcode.

Comment: Another magnificent answer.

Comment: Just don't _run_ them simultaneously.

Comment: Brilliant.  What do you say to my added note at the bottom of the question - is there a danger of horking the command line tools?  (I assume not, but a zillion googlers will come here, and you're the expert!  :)  )

Comment: @Fattie - See "Xcode" » "Preferences" » "Command line tools".

Comment: There isn't any "danger" of anything. I am using Xcode 9 beta 4, Xcode 9 beta 3, and Xcode 8.3, right now. End of story.

Comment: So, is this still true with Xcode 9 Gold Master (production).... I just downloaded Xcode 9 xip and have unpacked it.... not I am really nervous about running and configuring it since I have a large project on 8 which I am not ready to migrate, But I also need 9 for different project.

Comment: Yes, perfectly true. I'm still running both alternately. The old version is in a folder so there's no name conflict. (If I were you, though, I'd go straight for Xcode 9.1 beta and skip Xcode 9 altogether.)

Comment: @matt thanks. I will go straight for 9.1 beta then. good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

After Xcode 9 beta installation, all the simulators were gone.

To solve this, I removed the beta from the Applications folder and started using it from the desktop. The simulators reappeared in Xcode 8.

Then I moved the .app to the Applications folder again and all is working fine. I can even use both versions at the same time.

Comment: Just restarting Xcode fixed the missing simulators for me.