# Is it possible to install an old version of Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

Since https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/6083 Homebrew requires Xcode 10.2.1. However some projects I work on require Xcode 9.

How can I install an older version of Homebrew to work around this?

Comment: That might be the wrong approach. You can have multiple Xcode versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)