# How to install Xcode versions for Xamarin and MAUI on the same machine?

Tags: xcode, xamarin, migration, maui

I've been maintaining my Xamarin app in Visual Studio for Mac and decided to migrate it to MAUI using Visual Studio for Windows. I had upgraded to MacOS Sonoma, and found Xcode 14.3.1 (needed for Xamarin) no longer ran on Sonoma.

Foolishly, I deleted Xcode 14.3.1 and installed Xcode 15, which was needed anyway for MAUI.

Now I was in a pickle, because Xamarin does not work with Xcode 15. I needed to be able to check things out in Xamarin while my MAUI version is having open-heart surgery.

It took a while to see how to dig my way out, so I'll describe this in the solution below.

I was fortunate in one thing, that I had previously installed Xcode 14.3.1 and its command line tools. So those command line tools were still sitting safe and sound on my hard drive. Sonoma refuses to install 14.3.1 command line tools, either in Xcode preferences or using xcode-select.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

Comment: Xamarin can work with XCode 15. See October's announcement at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-maui-in-dotnet-8-rc-2/#bonus-2-xcode-15-and-android-api-34

Comment: Thank you @Rob Caplan - MSFT. What a relief!

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the version of Xcode recommended for MAUI (currently Xcode15) and its command line tools.
2. Determine its bundle version (right-click > Show package contents > Contents > SystemLibraries > Info.plist) - for Xcode15 this is 22502.
3. Download Xcode 14.3.1 from https://developer.apple.com/download/all/
4. Unzip the downloaded .xip file and rename Xcode.app to Xcode14.3.1 (use this exact name).
5. Do not attempt to run Xcode14.3.1 yet!
6. Place Xcode14.3.1 in the Applications folder and, using the procedure above, change its bundle version to the bundle version of the latest Xcode.
7. Do not run Xcode14.3.1 yet!
8. In Visual Studio Mac, go to Preferences > SDK locations > Apple, select /Applications/Xcode14.3.1.app as Location and restart Visual Studio.
9. Ignore the red bar through the Xcode14.3.1 icon: Xcode14.3.1 will now be runnable.

When switching from VS Windows to VS Mac:

1. Exit Visual Studio Windows and make sure Xcode is not running on Windows
2. In Visual Studio Mac, go to Preferences > SDK locations > Apple and select /Applications/Xcode14.3.1.app as Location
3. Restart Visual Studio Mac.

When switching from VS Mac to VS Windows:

1. In Visual Studio Mac, select /Applications/Xcode.app as the Location
2. Restart Visual Studio Mac then exit Visual Studio Mac; make sure Xcode is not running on Mac
3. Start Visual Studio Windows